# Missing Indent error in Python

Tags: python, netbeans-8.1

I am trying to run a python program of othello . But I know why it is showing error in 'copy'

[image: Please help me resolve it]

Comment: put indentation to the body of def

Comment: Please add your code as text (as everyone else does), not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

The body of a function definition must be indented.

Wrong:

```
def f():
print(1)
```

Right:

```
def f():
    print(1)
```